# How to tell if port can be read by client javascript

Tags: javascript, port, detection, mediaelement.js

I have a javascript webradio that can read a feed from different ports.
I did plenty of detections to try and determine why some people have trouble listening to the radio.
Now I'm guessing that maybe some clients cannot read some ports and thus, the stream would not play.

I want to test whether the ports can actually be read from the client and determine if it is meaningful to dynamically add that stream in my playlist or not (using javascript).

I read how to verify if a port is opened with PHP but it's always from the server side. I know my server can read that port, but maybe the proxy/firewall/ISP is actually blocking the port closer to the client.

Is there a way to verify that the client has those ports opened?

Comment: How are you opening the connection with JS? Please show us your code.

Comment: it's fairly complicated actually. Basically, it's a webradio built on top of mediaelementjs. I "open the connection" when I load the file using mediaelement.load(). However, I would like to verify beforehand if it is worth the try.

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do but pass a fail handler to `load()`

Comment: I see. So there is no way to detect beforehand. That's too bad. Thank for the help.